# CoreData fault - how to get data

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship, fault

I've researched tons of questions and documents about CoreData returning faults instead of actual values:

```
Relationship 'whiskers' fault on managed object (0xb7abab0)
```

This happens when I'm trying to get the count for the number of whiskers, such as:

```
self.numWhiskersLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", cat.whiskers.count];
```

Even if I try to log the whiskers set directly I still get a fault:

```
NSLog(@"whiskers: %@", cat.whiskers);
```

I understand that "Core data will not return full object until there is a need to access the actual value of that object. Each of your returned objects will be a 'fault' until this point." That's great, but **there is a need to access the actual value** at this point. I need the value right now! So how do I get out of this oxymoron? How can accessing the count of a Set not be considered needing the value?

Comment: So you have done a fetch request on Cat right ? Then the Cat object should be there and ready for you to access the whiskers. What is the data type of whiskers ?

Comment: What datatype is whiskers? A set of NSManagedObjects?

Comment: What does it show in your label? -- Your calls to get the data should work, as you expect. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Have you tried ``[[cat mutableSetValueForKey:@"whiskers"] count]`` ? There are a number of things that could be going wrong here, and most of them would be in the implementation of your model object and/or the relationships to the whiskers objects. Are you using thread confinement or queue confinement?

Comment: Try iterating over the cat.whiskers to see if there are any.

Comment: Is whiskers an ordered or normal relationship? If it is ordered, try the normal one. There were problems with ordered relationships at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error condition.  Something is wrong with that `NSManagedObject` instance.  Either it was deleted before you accessed it or you are trying to touch it from the wrong thread.

Please edit your question and show the code that is accessing that `NSManagedObject`.

Also, what happens when, in the debugger, you just do a `po cat`?  Do you see the full `Cat` object or is that giving a fault error as well?

Comment: In this case it was something wrong with the NSManagedObject instance.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get any feedback from my comment so I'm just going to assume whiskers is a set of NSManagedObjects

The set wont be loaded initially because internally it's coming from another table in the db. When you access *.whiskers.count* it still doesn't need to go and get the data yet, because all you're wanting is the number of whiskers in the set.

When you pull a whisker out of the set, then it will be faulted, try doing

```
NSLog(@"whiskers: %@", [cat.whiskers.anyObject anyProperty]);
```

That should give you a loaded NSManagedObject.

Comment: No, to get a count of the objects in the relationship it still has to fire the fault for the objects in relationship. It does NOT have to fire faults on the properties of those objects. And cat.whiskers.count is really a good way to get the count of objects in a relationship. Correct use of key value collection operators, NSExpression, or a subquery are all much better solutions for a number of reasons.

Comment: @quellish that's exactly what I just said - when getting the 'count' of items in the NSSet, it will go to the database and only select the objectIDs of the whiskers, no other properties/columns

Comment: No, your statement " When you access .whiskers.count it still doesn't need to go and get the data yet" is misleading. It still has to access the persistent store to satisfy the count expression. Even if it's not faulting the objects that are the target of the relationship, it has to fault *the relationship*. And faulting the relationship is where he is having a problem.